# How to set a property value from an expression?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, expression

I need orientation on this scenario. For example I have this class:

```
public class Schema
{
   public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

On the front end the user will have the chance to enter the value for that property:

**Schema.Value  = [Expression here]**

Now the user can call a function that returns a string, or he can concatenate Values from different schemas to assign the value to that particular schema value property.

How is the best way to do it? I find this difficult to explain, but how do I save that expression (the mechanism) and then calculate it during runtime?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If you're doing this at runtime based on user-defined _expressions_, then consider using an expression evaluator like [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/) or [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CodeDomProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx) class to evaluate expressions at runtime, or script engines like [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/).
Here is a simple test which evaluates a `DateTime` expression:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExecuteTest()
{
    CodeDomProvider provider = provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
    cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
    cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
    cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
    string source = @"using System; namespace N { public class C { public static DateTime Execute() { return DateTime.Now.AddDays(10); } } }";
    CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, source);
    if(cr.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("  {0}", ce.ToString());
        }
        Assert.Fail("Compilation error(s).");
    }
    else
    {
        object obj = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("N.C");
        MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var actual = (DateTime)mi.Invoke(obj, null);
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        var expected = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).Date;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Date);
    }
}
```

This code requires reflection to discover the `C` class and `Execute` method. You will need to import `System.Reflection` and `System.CodeDom.Compiler` namespaces.

You have to be careful what classes / methods you expose in the expressions, because it can be a big security issue. You can add your own classes, add references from external  assemblies, etc. and you don't have control on what is being executed.